# Determine whether this series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am studying for a calculus final and have come across this practice question:

$\text{Determine whether the series is absolutely convergent:}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^n [1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dotsm \cdot (2n     - 1)]}{(2n - 1)!}$

So far, I know I need to use the Ratio Test and have worked my way to the following step:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\lvert\frac{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)!)}{(2n + 1)!(2n - 1)} \right\rvert$

I know by looking at the answer key that the answer is that indeed the series converges. This implies that the result is less than one.

How can I simplify my step to achieve such an answer?

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The convergence of a series does not imply that the limit of the ratios of successive terms tends to a number less than  $1$.

Comment: I stated that the convergence of a series imply that the limit of the ratios of successive terms tends to a value less than 1.

Comment: Fixed "typo".${}$

Comment: Hint: The numerator of the summand contains all odd numbers from $1$ to $2n-1$ while the denominator contains all number from $1$ to $2n-1$.

Comment: The $2n-1$ at the bottom is I think not correct. (The $(2n-1)!$ is fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this   is what you're asking:

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac {(2n+1)(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!(2n-1)}|= \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac {(2n-2)!}{(2n)!}|= \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac {1}{(2n)(2n-1)}|=0$

Comment: How did you simplify the first step to the second?

Comment: Basically $\frac {2n+1}{(2n+1)!}=\frac {1}{(2n)!}$ and $\frac {(2n-1)!}{(2n-1)}=(2n-2)!$

Comment: Alright, I got that. Now how about the second step to third?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Recall that $(n+2)! = (n+2)\cdot(n+1)\cdot n!$

Comment: What about $(n - 2)!$

Comment: it may come as a surprise but is $(n-2)! = (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)!$

Answer (score 1):

Try first some algebraic simplification:

$$\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{(2n-1)!}=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)(2n)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)(2n-1)!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!(2n-1)!}=\frac1{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}$$

and now it looks, imo, much simpler:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}{2^nn!}=\frac1{2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\ldots$$